# Converting my C++ code to C# using QueryPerformanceFrequency() and QueryPerformanceCounter()?

Tags: c#

I've been converting my game over from C++ to C#. I was curious how the timer was going to work with C#'s absence of QueryPerformanceFrequency() and QueryPerformanceCounter(), because I need the total time and delta. How can I convert my code to C# using the functions I previously had?

I'll just step through this section by section:

I was using this timer code for C++:

```
#include "HPTimer.h"

/// <summary>
/// HP Timer constructor
/// </summary>
HPTimer::HPTimer()
{
    init();
}

/// <summary>
/// Initializes the timer
/// </summary>
void HPTimer::init()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER t;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&t);
    m_frequency = t.QuadPart;

    reset();
}

/// <summary>
/// Sets the current time. 
/// </summary>
void HPTimer::reset()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER t;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t);

    m_startTime = t.QuadPart;
    m_currentCallToUpdate = t.QuadPart;
    m_lastCallToUpdate = t.QuadPart; 
}

/// <summary>
/// Updates the timer so it's current. 
/// </summary>
void HPTimer::update()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER t;

    m_lastCallToUpdate = m_currentCallToUpdate; 
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t); 
    m_currentCallToUpdate = t.QuadPart;
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the total time since reset was called.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Returns the total time.</returns>
double HPTimer::getTimeTotal()
{
    double d;

    d = m_currentCallToUpdate - m_startTime; 
    return d / m_frequency;
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the difference between two calls of update. 
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Returns the delta time.</returns>
double HPTimer::getTimeDelta()
{
    double d;

    d = m_currentCallToUpdate - m_lastCallToUpdate;
    return d / m_frequency;
}
```

Microsoft's solution is the following:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650674.aspx

```
// QueryPerfCounter.cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class QueryPerfCounter
{
  [DllImport("KERNEL32")]
  private static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(
    out long lpPerformanceCount);

  [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
  private static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(out long lpFrequency);

  private long start;
  private long stop;
  private long frequency;
  Decimal multiplier = new Decimal(1.0e9);

  public QueryPerfCounter()
  {
    if (QueryPerformanceFrequency(out frequency) == false)
    {
      // Frequency not supported
      throw new Win32Exception();
    }
  }

  public void Start()
  {
    QueryPerformanceCounter(out start);
  }

  public void Stop()
  {
    QueryPerformanceCounter(out stop);
  }

  public double Duration(int iterations)
  {
    return ((((double)(stop - start)* (double) multiplier) / (double) frequency)/iterations);
  }
}
```

While this seems efficient, it's missing a few parts I used before: LARGE_INTEGER, QuadPart, getting the total time, and getting the time delta. In Microsoft's code, they have this 'iteration' argument that I'm confused on. Is there a way my code can be converted over while still using my earlier functions?

Edit:
I was curious about LARGE_INTEGER/QuadPart. I went here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383713(v=vs.85).aspx
I guess LARGE_INTEGER is really a long in C#'s world (64-bit). So t.QuadPart is treated as the out long value, right?

Update:
After reviewing the answers, I have the following conversion (but still need confirmation)

```
public class HPTimer
{ 
    private long m_startTime;
    private long m_lastCallUpdate;
    private long m_currentCallToUpdate;
    private long m_frequency;
    private Stopwatch m_stopWatch;

    /// <summary>
    /// HP Timer constructor
    /// </summary>
    public HPTimer()
    {
        Init(); 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the timer
    /// </summary>
    public void Init()
    {
        m_stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 
        m_frequency = Stopwatch.Frequency; 

        Reset();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resets the current time. 
    /// </summary> 
    public void Reset()
    {
        m_startTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
        m_currentCallToUpdate = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
        m_lastCallUpdate = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp(); 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the timer so it's current. 
    /// </summary>
    public void Update()
    {
        m_lastCallUpdate = m_currentCallToUpdate;
        m_currentCallToUpdate = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the total time since reset was called.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns the total time.</returns>
    public double GetTotalTime()
    {
        double d;

        d = m_currentCallToUpdate - m_startTime;
        return d / m_frequency;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the difference between two calls of update. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns the delta time.</returns>
    public double GetTimeDelta()
    {
        double d;

        d = m_currentCallToUpdate - m_lastCallUpdate;

        return d / m_frequency;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of unmanaged Win32 API to record time.   Example:

```
//Equivalent to:
//Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
//stopWatch.Start();
Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

//Operation you want to measure

stopWatch.Stop();

//Timespan is a struct to hold time related info..
//e.g: Days, Hours, Seconds, Milliseconds, Ticks and TotalDays... etc
Timespan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

//Or you can simply get the time elapsed in milliseconds like this
long elapsed = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;


//QueryPerformanceFrequency 
long frequency = Stopwatch.Frequency;

//QueryPerformanceCounter
long ticks = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
```

As for your other question regarding LARGE_INTEGER. Its C# equivalent according to [`this page`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383713(v=vs.85).aspx) should be:

```
//Specify struct size and field offsets by ourselves
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 8)]
struct LARGE_INTEGER
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint LowPart;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public int HighPart;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public long QuadPart;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you can't use [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)?  It will generally use the high performance counter if it can (there's a [static field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution(v=vs.110).aspx) which tells you if it is using the high performance counter).

You can simply create a `Stopwatch`, then record its [`Elapsed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx) property every update.  It's of type `TimeSpan` which overloads subtraction so you can get deltas easily.